# Conditionally format each cell containing the max value of a row in a data frame - R Markdown PDF

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, kable, kableextra

I am using R Markdown to create a PDF document with a few tables.

Here is the example necessary data

```
output:
  pdf_document:
  toc: yes

require("pacman")
p_load(tidyverse, reshape, reshape2, knitr, kableExtra, tinytex, scales, pander, janitor, gridExtra)

segment<- c('seg1', 'seg1', 'seg2', 'seg2', 'seg3', 'seg3')
subSegment<- c('subseg1', 'subseg2', 'subseg1', 'subseg2', 'subseg1', 'subseg2')
var.1<- c(100, 20, 30, 50, 40, 40)
var.2<- c(200, 30, 30, 70, 30, 140)
var.3<- c(50, 50, 40, 20, 30, 40)
var.4<- c(60, 50, 35, 53, 42, 20)
df<- data.frame(segment, subSegment, var.1, var.2, var.3, var.4)
df%>%adorn_totals('row')

df.2<-df
df.2[c(3:ncol(df.2))] = sapply(df.2[c(3:ncol(df.2))], function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = 0.1))

df.2 %>%
  kable(format = "latex", booktabs = TRUE, caption = "Title" ,align = "c") %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", "repeat_header", "scale_down"), font_size = 6) %>%
  group_rows(index = table(fct_inorder(df$`segment`)), italic = F, bold = F, underline = T, latex_gap_space = "1em", background = "#f2f2f2")%>%
  column_spec(1, monospace = T, color = "white") %>%
  row_spec(nrow(df), bold = T)
```

I know how to use column_spec to conditionally change the format of a column, for example:

```
column_spec(ncol(df), color = ifelse(df$var.4 > 50, "green","red"))
```

I would like to give the format  'bold = T' to the cell with the maximum value in each row...

Is there a simple way to do so? this is just an example but my real df has hundreds of rows and over 20 columns so doing it manually is really not an option... I found some similar questions but mostly solving this for HTML knitting.

I trid something like:

```
 df[3:ncol(df)] <- lapply(df[3:ncol(df)], function(x) {
     cell_spec(x,  font_size = spec_font_size(x))
    })
```

but that didn't work and even if it did the results are not really what I am looking for as they change the size instead of making the maximum bold.

Short description: highlight the maximum value of each row in a data frame
Edited: edited to add that numbers have a special format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using dplyr::mutate(across... and max(c_across... is one way:

````
---
output:
  pdf_document:
  toc: yes
---

```{r, include=FALSE}

require("pacman")
p_load(dplyr, forcats, knitr, kableExtra, tinytex, janitor)

segment<- c('seg1', 'seg1', 'seg2', 'seg2', 'seg3', 'seg3')
subSegment<- c('subseg1', 'subseg2', 'subseg1', 'subseg2', 'subseg1', 'subseg2')
var.1<- c(100, 20, 30, 50, 40, 40)
var.2<- c(200, 30, 30, 70, 30, 140)
var.3<- c(50, 50, 40, 20, 30, 40)
var.4<- c(60, 50, 35, 53, 42, 20)

df <- 
  data.frame(segment, subSegment, var.1, var.2, var.3, var.4) %>% 
  adorn_totals('row') %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(across(var.1:var.4,  ~cell_spec(.x, 'latex', bold = ifelse(.x == max(c_across(var.1:var.4)), TRUE,  FALSE))))
  
```

```{r, results='asis'}


df %>%
  kable(booktabs = TRUE,
        caption = "Title",
        align = "c",
        escape = FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = c("HOLD_position", "repeat_header", "scale_down"),
                font_size = 6) %>%
  pack_rows(index = table(fct_inorder(df$segment)),
             italic = FALSE,
             bold = FALSE,
             underline = TRUE,
             latex_gap_space = "1em",
             background = "#f2f2f2")%>%
  column_spec(1, monospace = TRUE, color = "white") %>%
  row_spec(nrow(df), bold = TRUE)

```
````

Which results in this pdf output:

[image]

Comment: instead of actually printing what you have, I get the following: \textbf{number}

Comment: Is there some extra package or setup I need for this to actually work?

Comment: Does this happen with the answer code or your own data and code? I've just run the answer in a fresh session as an .Rmd file and it works fine. Check you have set `escape = FALSE` in `kable(...)`

Comment: you are rigth, it works great on the example data I gave here, it just doesn't work on my own data, probably cause of some formatting I did. I will try to figure it out and maybe update the example. Thanks

Comment: I believe the problem is that my numbers are actually percentages and I have used scales::percent

Comment: Is your question resolved by the answer?

Comment: yes. this question how I formulated it was resolved. I will formulate a new question that will better replicate my case.

Comment: I have updated a new question which better reflects my problem, you are free to check it out if you have the time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71480495/r-markdown-pdf-table-with-conditional-bold-formating-and-percentage-format